# How to prove $x^{-1} x^{-1} x^{-1} ... x^{-1} = x^{-n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the text I read, it says that $x x x ... x$ could be denoted by $x^n$, but then it goes by saying that $x^{-1} x^{-1} x^{-1} ... x^{-1}$ could also be denoted by $x^{-n}$. Is it just enough? Or if there is a proof of it, what is it?

Here is the text:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to be proved here, this is how we define $x^{-n}$. You can trivially verify that $(x^{-1})^n=(x^n)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not something that you prove; this is a definition. For an integer $n>0$, $x^n$ is $n$ factors of $x$ multiplied together, and $x^{-n}$ is $n$ factors of $x^{-1}$ multiplied together.

Comment: So it is just enough?

Comment: @AriRoyceHidayat It is enough to define the notation, yes.

Comment: It says "Denote... by..." which means this is a definition. The text is defining $x^{-n}$ to mean $\underbrace{x^{-1}x^{-1}\cdots x^{-1}}_n$.